# How to sign maven publications with gradle

Tags: gradle, signing, gnupg

Have such `build.gradle` script that uses new publishing plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'signing'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

// ...

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java

            artifact sourcesJar {
                classifier 'source'
            }
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            name 'Temporary'
            url "file://${rootProject.buildDir}/repo"
        }
    }
}

signing {
    sign configurations.archives
}
```

So the questions are:

1. How to sign maven pom?
2. How to publish signatures to maven repository?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The new, incubating `maven-publish` plugin doesn't support signing yet.

Comment: Thanks, so will rollback to use `maven` plugin.

Comment: Would love to see signing and username/pass supported for those that need to publish opensource code into maven central.

Comment: For the time being, you'll have to use the `maven` plugin.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser, I'm not sure what you mean when you say that the "maven-publish plugin doesn't support signing yet". given that the signing plugin in the example above works just fine, i.e. produces .asc files as expected, isn't this really about finding a way to tell the maven-publish plugin to simply upload them like any other artifact?

Comment: As of Gradle 2.2, my answer is still valid.

Comment: This is November 2015 now so nearly a year after; I'm using gradle 2.9, is this still the case that this plugin does not support signing? :/

Comment: As of 2021, does the publishing plugin support signing?

Comment: @Greg It's supported now https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_signing.html

Answer (score 4):

While it still [not officially](https://docs.gradle.org/4.1/userguide/signing_plugin.html#sec:signing_pom_files) supported, it is nonetheless possible to upload signed artifacts using the signing and the maven-publish  plugin.

First, we set up our signing section as usual:

```
apply plugin: 'signing'

signing {
  sign configurations.archives
}
```

This will sign the project's archive. To sign the POM that is created by the maven-publish plugin, we add a sign task:

```
task signPom(type: Sign) {
  sign project.file('build/publications/maven/pom-default.xml')
  outputs.upToDateWhen { false }  // the signing plugin does not seem to notice
                                  // it when the publications folder with the
                                  // signature has been deleted. So we always
                                  // create a new signature
}
```

It is not possible to simply add a `sign generatePomFileForMavenPublication` line
to `signing` as the maven-plublish plugin [leverages support for late
configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:generate-pom) which means that the task for generating the pom is not available when configuring the signing section.

Now we have all the signature files we need. We only need to add them to the
publication:

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

publishing {
  publications {
    maven(MavenPublication) {
      from components.java

      project.tasks.withType(Sign) {
        signatures.all {
          def type = it.type
          if (it.file.name.endsWith('.tar.gz.asc')) {  // Workaround in case a tar.gz file should published
            type = 'tar.gz.asc'
          } else if (it.type.equals('xml.asc')) {  // Set correct extension for signature of pom file
            type = 'pom.asc'
          }
          artifact source: it.file, classifier: it.classifier ?: null, extension: type
        }
      }

      pom.withXml {
        // The pom can be enriched as usual
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This takes all signature files created by the build and adds them as artifacts to the publication. In order to have the pom file correctly named, the file extension xml.asc need to be replaced with pom.asc (the maven-publish plugin stores the pom locally as *pom-default.xml*).

With all tasks being there and connected with each other, the last thing to do
is to set up the dependencies in the model:

```
model {
  tasks.publishMavenPublicationToMavenLocal {
    dependsOn project.tasks.withType(Sign)
  }
  tasks.publishMavenPublicationToNexusLocalSnapshotsRepository {
    dependsOn project.tasks.withType(Sign)
  }
  tasks.signPom {
    dependsOn tasks.generatePomFileForMavenPublication
  }
}
```

The name of the second task depends on the name of the repository in the
`publications.repository` section. Mine is called "NexusLocalSnapshots".

The only disadvantage of this approach is that for each signature files an md5
and sha1 checksum file is created. This does not seem to be a problem for the
repository manager, though (tested locally with Nexus 3).

Comment: Does Gradle support signing maven publications yet, in 6.5 or 7? I appear to have the signing plugin working to sign my artifacts, but they are no longer being uploaded. Before I set up signing, the unsigned artifacts were being uploaded...